# electron-forge --template argument does not work

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I just installed electron-forge following the its homepage instructions but when I try to create a new project from angular2 template, it creates the default Vanilla template.
These commands I used:

```
npm install -g electron-forge
electron-forge init my-new-project --template=angular2
```

I reinstalled it twice and still the same problem.

**Update:**

Output of

DEBUG=electron-forge* electron-forge init my-new-project --template=angular2

```
WARNING: DEBUG environment variable detected.  Progress indicators will be sent over electron-forge:lifecycle
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Started: Checking your system +0ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Succeeded: Checking your system +14ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config setting key: verbose to value: false +6ms
WARNING: DEBUG environment variable detected.  Progress indicators will be sent over electron-forge:lifecycle
  electron-forge:init Initializing in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +0ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Started: Initializing Project Directory +2ms
  electron-forge:init:directory creating directory: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +1ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Succeeded: Initializing Project Directory +3ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Started: Initializing Git Repository +1ms
  electron-forge:init:git executing "git init" in directory: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +1ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Succeeded: Initializing Git Repository +8ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Started: Copying Starter Files +0ms
  electron-forge:init:starter-files creating directory: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project/src +1ms
  electron-forge:init:starter-files copying "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/tmpl/_gitignore" --> "/home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project/.gitignore" +1ms
  electron-forge:init:starter-files copying "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/tmpl/_compilerc" --> "/home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project/.compilerc" +1ms
  electron-forge:init:starter-files copying "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/tmpl/_eslintrc" --> "/home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project/.eslintrc" +0ms
  electron-forge:init:starter-files copying "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/tmpl/index.js" --> "/home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project/src/index.js" +1ms
  electron-forge:init:starter-files copying "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/tmpl/index.html" --> "/home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project/src/index.html" +0ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Succeeded: Copying Starter Files +0ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Started: Initializing NPM Module +1ms
  electron-forge:init:npm writing package.json to: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +4ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Succeeded: Initializing NPM Module +1ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Started: Installing NPM Dependencies +0ms
  electron-forge:init:npm installing dependencies +1ms
  electron-forge:dependency-installer installing ["electron-compile"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project dev=false,exact=false,withYarn=false +3ms
  electron-forge:dependency-installer executing ["install","electron-compile","--save"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +1ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +3ms
  electron-forge:init:npm installing devDependencies +11s
  electron-forge:dependency-installer installing ["babel-preset-env","babel-preset-react","babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project dev=true,exact=false,withYarn=false +0ms
  electron-forge:dependency-installer executing ["install","babel-preset-env","babel-preset-react","babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator","--save-dev"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +3ms
  electron-forge:init:npm installing exact dependencies +11s
  electron-forge:dependency-installer installing ["electron-prebuilt-compile"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project dev=true,exact=true,withYarn=false +1ms
  electron-forge:dependency-installer executing ["install","electron-prebuilt-compile","--save-exact","--save-dev"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +2ms
  electron-forge:init:npm installing airbnb linting dependencies +44s
  electron-forge:dependency-installer installing ["eslint","eslint-config-airbnb","eslint-plugin-import","eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y","eslint-plugin-react"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project dev=true,exact=false,withYarn=false +0ms
  electron-forge:dependency-installer executing ["install","eslint","eslint-config-airbnb","eslint-plugin-import","eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y","eslint-plugin-react","--save-dev"] in: /home/jotaeler/projects/my-new-project +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +0ms
  electron-forge:runtime-config fetching key verbose +2ms
  electron-forge:lifecycle Process Succeeded: Installing NPM Dependencies +19s
```

Comment: Just tested it out and this works perfectly for me, can you make a gist with the output from this command and link it here.  `DEBUG=electron-forge* electron-forge init my-new-project --template=angular2`

Comment: @MarshallOfSound I've updated the question with the output, thanks!

Comment: That is actually super weird, can you post the output of `electron-forge --version`

Comment: I just released a new version of electron forge which fixes this bug ;)

Comment: @MarshallOfSound Thanks you very much! I was getting crazy! I will test it in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as @MarshallOfSound released the new version it works fine